# Numbers Not Correctly Formatted When New Row Added Via Integromat

Tags: google-sheets

I'm importing data into a Google Sheet via Integromat. Column A is a Date and Column B is a time. Both columns have been selected and formatted appropriately (Format > Number > Date and Format > Number > Time).

Things have been working perfectly but all of a sudden when new rows are added via Integtomat, instead of the correctly formatted date & time I'm getting an unformatted number. For example, 44560 instead of 12/30/2021 and .5833333333 instead of 2:00:00 PM. If I select an entire column and go to Format > Number I can see that the formatting is still applied. But in order to get the new row to format correctly, I need to reapply the formatting.

I have no clue why it's not formatting the new numbers correctly as this has been working for over a month without a problem. Nothing has changed on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. You've flagged this as a `Google-Sheet` issue, but you haven't provided any information about how the data is formatted in Integromat - have you raised this question with Integromat help, and what was their response?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to **Insert > Sheet** and copy all values from the Import sheet with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) in cell `A1` of the new sheet, like this:

`={ Import!A1:Z }`

Format the new sheet the way you need. Formats will stick there.